# I want a jquery function to show the hidden list items on successful login

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

```
<li id="liAfterLogin" runat="server" style="display:none;"><a class="drop" href="#">Articles</a>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="Category.aspx">Categories</a></li>
    <li><a href="PopularArticles.aspx">Popular Articles</a></li>
    <li><a href="MostReadArticles.aspx">Most Read</a></li>
    <li><a href="RecentArticles.aspx">Recent Articles</a></li>
    <li><a href="Home.aspx">Quick Links</a></li>
  </ul>

</li>
```

I have hidden the Articles list item but I need a jQuery function which will display the Articles list item on a successful login. the login is verified from a table which stores the userid and password. Please help in providing a jQuery function

Comment: `jQuery("#liAfterLogin").show();`

Comment: but my liAfterLogin control is a masterpage control and my login page is content page. how to call this jQuery function which is in master page  on the loginbutton cick event which is on content page ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with :

```
$("#liAfterLogin").show();
```

Comment: but my liAfterLogin control is a masterpage control and my login page is content page. how to call this jQuery function which is in master page  on the loginbutton cick event which is on content page ?

Comment: $("#yourButton").click(function(){
    $("#liAfterLogin").show();
});

Comment: not working its not able to find the liAfterLogin control of master page in login page

Comment: In this case you need to test if the user is logged in the master page and show the menu if it's true, for example :
if (userLogged){$("#liAfterLogin").show();}

But I don't know exactly your structure, we need more information.

Comment: con.Open();
            string checkPassword = "SELECT Password FROM AdminLoginDetailsTbl WHERE UserID='" + TextBoxUN.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmdpwd = new SqlCommand(checkPassword, con);
            string password = cmdpwd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            HtmlGenericControl myUI = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.Master.FindControl("liAfterLogin");

            if (password == TextBoxPWD.Text)
            {
                Session["New"] = TextBoxUN.Text;
                myUI.Style.Add("display","block");
                Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
            }

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $("#liAfterLogin").css("display", "block");
});
```